# Typescript, react error Property '[Invalid_propTypes]' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

Suddenly all my antd components started to give the same error

> "Property '[Invalid_propTypes]' is missing in type...Property
>   '[Invalid_propTypes]' is missing in type '{ children: Element; locale:
>   { locale: string; Pagination: any; DatePicker: { lang: any;
>   timePickerLocale: { placeholder: string; }; }; TimePicker: {
>   placeholder: string; }; Calendar: { lang: any; timePickerLocale: {
>   ...; }; }; ... 5 more ...; Upload: { ...; }; }; }'."

The message above is an example error message that I'm receiving in a

Here follows my package.json

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/antd": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.40",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.6",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.7",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.4.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.16",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "enquire-js": "^0.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.10",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "peity-react": "0.0.7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-container-query": "^0.11.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-redux-spinner": "^1.1.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-router5": "^6.5.3",
    "react-saga": "^0.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-act": "^1.7.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "ts-jest": "22.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "main": "dist/index",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.118",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.6",
    "@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
    "antd": "^3.10.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.(j|t)s?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).(j|t)s?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/typescriptTransform.js",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "/home/julio/Documents/Enlyze/dash/dashboard/tsconfig.test.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my tslint.json

```
    {
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
      "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "member-access": {
      "options": ["no-public"]
    },
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "variable-name": [false],
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "no-console": false
  }
}
```

I don't know what happened but everything was working before this sudden error. Any help will appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try to add `declare module 'antd';` in *.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem about [@types/react](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/30730)，just need upgrade @types/react to the latest version。

```
yarn upgrade @types/react@latest
```